# Castle DynamicProxy DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxyType does not work with proxy generators

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

I am trying to create a proxy type using mixins. In the following example, TypePresenter implements ICustomTypeDescriptor. When I create an instance the "GetProperties" throws a NotImplementedException.

When I do the same thing with ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy, everything works fine! I want to get the type so that I can use it with my IoC.

```
var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions();
options.AddMixinInstance(new TypePresenter<SampleViewModel>());

var builder = new DefaultProxyBuilder();
var sampleType = builder.CreateClassProxyType(typeof(SampleViewModel), null, options);
var sample = Activator.CreateInstance(sampleType);

var typeDescriptor = (ICustomTypeDescriptor)sample;

// Error happens on this line.
var properties = typeDescriptor.GetProperties();

var property = properties["DoIt"];
Assert.IsNotNull(property);
Assert.IsTrue(property.PropertyType == typeof(ICommand));
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your sample object from the `Activator`; since you are not using the Castle-DynamicProxy library to create the proxy the mixin properties cannot work since the wiring behind the mixin is done via an intereceptor.

You can simply create the sample first via the ProxyGenerator then cast it to `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, you don't really need its type:

```
var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions();
options.AddMixinInstance(new TypePresenter<SampleViewModel>());

var pg = new ProxyGenerator();
var sample = pg.CreateClassProxy<SampleViewModel>(options); 
// regarding
//var sampleType = sample.GetType();

var typeDescriptor = (ICustomTypeDescriptor)sample;

// Error doesn't happen anymore on this line.
var properties = typeDescriptor.GetProperties();
```

**Edit**
Reagrding building a type without knowing the constructor in advance, one can use the CreateClassProxy overload that takes an object[] of constructor parameters as an argument;

Given and interface that lets us define the parameters we will need for a type:

```
public interface IGiveConstructorParametersFor<T> {
    object[] Parameters {get;}
}
```

it is possible to register it against a concrete class (or even multiple concrete classes that would then be resolved depending on the scenario we are in). Then we can have the following method to build a type we don't know in advance with constructor parameters we don't know in advance:

```
public T Proxify<T>(IGiveConstructorParametersFor<T> constructorParametersForT) {
    var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions();
    options.AddMixinInstance(new TypePresenter<T>());

    var pg = new ProxyGenerator();
    var sample = pg.CreateClassProxy(typeof(T),
                                     null,
                                     options,
                                     constructorParametersForT.Parameters);

    var typeDescriptor = (ICustomTypeDescriptor)sample;
    var properties = typeDescriptor.GetProperties();
}
```

As long as any type can be mapped to an implementation of the constructor parameters interface at runtime, it doesn't need to know it beforehand

Comment: Thank you @samy for replying. If you read my question, I already said that a ProxyGenerator would work, but would be of little use when I try to use an IoC. I have since solved this problem. I will try to circle back to post the answer this weekend.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens I explained why the `Activator`-created object didn't implement the ICustomTypeDescription in the first part of the answer, but i don't understand why the ProxyGenerator option would be a problem with IOC

Comment: please provide some sample code of your solution using an IoC container where you do not know what will be passed to the constructor.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens I edited my answer; Does the use of the `object` array matches what you were thinking regarding constructing a proxified object based on IoC?

Comment: I feel that we are going around in circles. I do not see the IoC code in your example. I am using Autofac, perhaps you can demonstrate how autofac is going to resolve constructor parameters with your method. @samy

Comment: Usually IoC is not seen after the first setup, since the roots will resolve the whole dependency tree. In the case of my example the `IGiveConstructorParametersFor` is supposed to be injected by the IoC, not resolved explicitly. However i can see why you're feeling that we're going in circles. Maybe re-stating the question, and.or a chat session would be more productive. If so, feel free to let me know